# How to make condition for Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Scenario is that I have a splash screen which reads a password from device. If found password then go to Main Activity, else, go to other activity.

I have problem in making condition. Kindly help me out for example:

```
SharedPreferences oPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("RegistrationData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String pin = oPref.getString("mobileNumebr", " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
        String pin = oPref.getString("mobileNumebr", " ");

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (pin.equals("")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashPage.this, LoginActivity.class));
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashPage.this, HomePage.class));
            }
            finish();
         }
        }.start();
```

Comment: While I am using your code I am not able to go to mainActiviti

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String pin = oPref.getString("mobileNumebr", "");

if(pin.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
go to other activity
}
  else
  {
go to main activity
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You should use the TextUtills class of android and check like this:

```
SharedPreferences oPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("RegistrationData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String pin = oPref.getString("mobileNumebr", "");//default value should be empty
if(TextUtills.isEmpty(pin)){
//Go to main activity
}else {
//Go to login Activity
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
      String pin=String pin = oPref.getString("mobileNumebr", "");
      if(pin!=null && !pin.isEmpty()){
            --go to main activity--
       }else{
            -- go to other activity--
          }
```